# How do I web-scrape and load specific DIV to my website from another?

Tags: jquery, html, web-scraping

I have looked and looked and I can't seem to find anything like I want. I am not the best at javascript so now I am asking for help. I use **JQuery** on my site. I want to be able to call a specific element like #body or #item from a website like **NewEgg** or **Walmart** or **Bestbuy**, (**not an iframe or popup**) and have it displayed into a predefined div already set on my website. As long as it atleast loads the content if not the css thats fine, im good with css. Example:

```
<div id="webscrape" class"www.blah.com/blahhh">
  <div id="website's div">content of specific newegg or reddit div/divs</div></div>
```

I also want to be able to have 2 javascripts, one to call the page into raw data to predefined div, and one for arguments to set the website and div element. Basically I want jquery to pull data exactly how it appears on the other website between a pre-defined div. I want this so I can show news and custom searches of products that are 4-5 star. I would also like to be able to call multiple divs on one page if possible. I have looked and looked and I can not find anything.

Comment: You're going to need to do this server-side, as I doubt these sites are enabling CORS.  Also, be sure you are legally allowed to do this.

Comment: The best you can probably hope for us using `getJSON` to access their API (if they have one) -- otherwise you're going to run into cross-site problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to cross site scripting rules - you either need to copy all the code from the existing site and update it manually (which is copy write infringement) or you need to see if the site has some kind of product display API that third parties can use.

The API's will usually be some kind of server side language like PHP or .net etc.

Comment: But it would be possible to do server-side, as @Brad pointed out.

Comment: didn't see his answer - but as he said, I doubt the sites allow it

Comment: it is, i have seen some examples but they are outdated and dont work, or do i have the knowledge yet to correct them

Comment: @computerguy If you want to know how to do this on the server-side, which is the only way it might be possible, I suggest that you start a new question tagged with the server-side language you're using.

Comment: there has to be some way to do this

Answer (score 0):

i was kind of developing something like that(not exactly what u r doing). With javascript it is not possible because of [Cross Site Scripting Issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Javascript can call content from the same domain, for different domain , use server-side technology, i am using PHP.

with js u can call a php file, which can get the content of that site.

```
$.get("webscrape.php", {"site":"http://www.scrapeme.com"}, function(data){
 alert(data); 
});
```

Just came accross this **Cross Domain Jquery Plugin**
if u want, u can give it a try.. it uses YQL

[Cross Domain Jquery github](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)

[example](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)